# Godot Node Reference/Documentation

Tags: nodes, document, godot, godot4

I'm just trying to learn Godot. It seems to work on Nodes, so it would be really helpful to have a reference document dedicated to Nodes, so I can look up what they do, so that when I start a project, I can decide which node I should use. I just started a [tutorial](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/pcg/world-map/) that uses a `Control` node as root. Why? I don't know. I know about the [manual](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/) and I've enabled Godot on [Devdocs](https://devdocs.io/) but neither of these allow me to browse through Nodes and look up what they do. This I want.

Comment: Perhaps this: https://devdocs.io/godot~3.5/classes/class_node#class-node is the closest thing around to what I want.

Comment: Not having much luck with the tutorial I mentioned. Couldn't find `OpenSimplexNoise` so used `FastNoiseLite` needed to replace `export` with `@export` and `GradientTexture` with `GradientTexture1D`... seems like it is out of date.

Comment: Yep. GoDot doesn't work how it used to. That tutorial is broken for GoDot 4.1 and above.

Comment: Here is the list of Nodes with links to their documentation pages from the official documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/index.html#nodes - addendum: and here is the tutorials page: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/community/tutorials.html and the official tutorial: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**node3d will create a 3d scene**

its position will be the scene origin

**node2d will create a 2d scene**

its position will be the scene origin

**control will create a 2d scene**

it has no position

essentially, some 2d nodes (those with green icons), may need a control node to *control* some of their attributes

godot is built on classes - inheriting attributes necessary (node2d inherits from node etc.)

node is just the base class for all 'things' in godot
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html

godot docs may be useful to you in future for understanding the engine